# timepicker values not popup on top

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get timepicker value inside popup view. When popup view displays, then timepicker value is still hidden. I need to get these values on the front side. I added z-index value also. But it doesn't work. And Is there problem which timepicker js file use. Here I used `jquery.timepicker.min.js`
. [Here attached full code](https://codeshare.io/21ve9q) .(Line 133 has my problem) Datepicker is worked. But timepicker not work.

[image]

```css
.timepicker {
  color: #389fff;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<table class="timepicker">
  <tr>
    <td><label>Time</label></td>
    <td class="timepicker">
      <input type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please give me some advice. Thank you.

Comment: Which timepicker? A working snippet to reproduce the problem would help a lot.

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements to begin with.

Comment: @MatthiasSeifert I used "jt-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.min.js" . Do you have some idea.

Comment: @misorude so how can I solve this issue.

Comment: You can try if adding `position:relative` to the table cell fixes the issue; if that doesn’t work, then start by providing a proper [mcve].

Comment: Check for z-index for the popup and make it less than .timepicker index

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution to your problem. I hope it works.

```
.timepicker {
    position:relative;
    color: #389fff;
    z-index: 1025;
    top:10;
}
```

Comment: @LDS I add this code snippet. But same issue. Do you have some idea about this.

Comment: @Priyantha add the z-index style in table tag also

Comment: @LDS I updated my question in table tag. But it also doesn't work. Can u see my update question and please give me something.Can u update ur answer. Bcz im new to frontend. Thank you.

Comment: @Priantha I try in my system with cdn link send the anaswaer